# how to remove double quotes and escape it in specific parts of a string

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
{
    "QueryString": null,
    "ProjectName": ""24"",
    "SeasonName": "",
    "MemberName": "",
    "CompanyName": "",
    "CompanyRole": 0,
    "CompanyRoles": "",
    "Year": ""
}
```

I want to make it look like this (FOR ALL VALUES THAT HAVE DOUBLE QUOTES IN THEM -- in this case, only the value of property ProjectName has it) using the replace function:

```
{
    "QueryString": null,
    "ProjectName": "\"24\"",
    "SeasonName": "",
    "MemberName": "",
    "CompanyName": "",
    "CompanyRole": 0,
    "CompanyRoles": "",
    "Year": ""
}
```

How do I go about doing this in JavaScript?

Comment: Where does this invalid javascript come from ? You should correct the problem at its source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression :

```
var str = '{\
    "QueryString": null,\
    "ProjectName": ""24"",\
    "SeasonName": "",\
    "MemberName": "",\
    "CompanyName": "",\
    "CompanyRole": 0,\
    "CompanyRoles": "",\
    "Year": ""\
}';

str = str.replace(/""([^"]*)"",/g,'"\\"$1\\"",');
```

Comment: I only want to do this to the values that HAVE values within double quotes e.g. ""24"", ""hello"", and NOT things like just "". get it?

Comment: your edit did it. thanks. you're the man! I need to wait 7 mins before accepting ur answer tho.